# Nav Bar Animation / Transition using only CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations, navigationbar

So, I am attempting to make a pretty dope navigation menu bar **animation/transition** for my website to create a slick looking effect. My goal here is to use only CSS, and not add in any javascript that just complicate things. [This link has the kind of animation](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FZHKB3FGOLWN) I'm looking for. Just to give you guys an idea. (*Just browsing through W3 Schools to see what animation I'm looking for*).

The idea here is to change `topnav`'s `background-color` from page to page in as a smooth transition.

Here is what I currently have for my CSS styling. I am liking my current styling, but I just want to add in the transition from page to page for the `background-color` to act like a slider in a sort of way

```css
ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #4d4dff;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

ul.topnav li a.active {
  background-color: #00cc99;
  color: black;
  /* I would like to add in some sort of animations / transition here. */
}
```

```html
<ul class="topnav">
  <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
  <div class="menu">
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
      <!--Background when active-->
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <!--If I click on this page, it would transition the background COLOR to this page-->
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

**EDIT COMMENT FOR RESPONSE TO Muljayan**

Take a look at this example here https://youtu.be/oCUCWnbre0k?t=1014 and follow this code.

**HTML**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navigation {
  margin: 200px 20px;
  background: #383838;
  color: #FFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
  width: 1000px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.navigation li {
  width: 100px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
  border-right: 2px ridge #585858;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: 'ambleregular';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all .9s;
  -moz-transition: all .9s;
  -o-transition: all .9s;
  -ms-transition: all .9s;
  transition: all .9s;
}

.navigation li:hover {
  background: #FE980F;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}

.navigation li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
}

.navigation li a:hover {
  color: #333;
}


/* Search box    */

.search_box {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #3C3C3C;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.3em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.3em;
  -o-border-radius: 0.3em;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 228px;
  left: 765px;
  top: 204px;
}

.search_box form input[type="text"] {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #acacac;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 5px;
}


/* Final STEP  */

.search_box form input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url(images/search.png) no-repeat 0px 7px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#faf7fd">
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="search_box">
    <form>
      <input type="text" value="Search" onfocus="this.value = ''; {this.value='Search' ;}">
      <input type="submit " value=" ">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used transitions on the li and an animation on the a tags to achieve the effects you needed.  on each page without javascript you will have to change the classes out for the active page manually. 
Example: On the about page the about a tag would have the class lnk and all the other a tags would have aLnk this is to highlight the current page.

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333333;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
}

li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 34px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: ease-in-out .9s;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: orange;
  transition: ease-in-out .9s;
}

.aLnk {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: ease-in-out .9s;
}

.aLnk:hover {
  color: yellow;
  transition: ease-in-out .9s;
  animation-name: changeColor;
  animation-duration: .9s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinate;
}

@keyframes changeColor {
  10% {
    color: #000000;
  }
  100% {
    color: yellow;
  }
}

.active {
  background-color: orange;
}

.lnk {
  color: yellow;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.lnk:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="topnav">
    <li class="active"><a class="lnk" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="aLnk" href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="aLnk" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is not possible to do this with pure *CSS*. The reason for this being whenever you click on a link it loads a new page. To create the effect you desire it is necessary to keep in memory the previous background colour to cause the transition.

For example, if the final colours of the backgrounds are as follows

- home page => blue
- about page => red
- portfolio page => green

If you go from home page to the about page the transition should be blue to red but let's say you're going from the portfolio page to the about page the transition should be green to red.

With pure *CSS* there is no way of knowing if the previous page had blue or green to transition into the red in the about page.

I would suggest you learn some front end framework like React, Vue or Angular. With those,

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
    
.navigation {
  margin: 200px 20px;
  background: #383838;
  color: #FFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
  width: 1000px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
    
.navigation li {
  width: 100px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
  border-right: 2px ridge #585858;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: 'ambleregular';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all .9s;
  -moz-transition: all .9s;
  -o-transition: all .9s;
  -ms-transition: all .9s;
  transition: all .9s;
}

.navigation .active {
  background: #FE980F;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  animation: animatedNav 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}

@keyframes animatedNav {
  0% {background: #383838;}
  100% {background: #FE980F;}
}

.navigation li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
}

.navigation .active a {
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<!-- home.html --> 

     <body bgcolor="#faf7fd">
        <ul class="navigation">
          <li class="active"><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="./products.html">Products</a></li>
        </ul>
      </body>

<!-- products.html -->

     <body bgcolor="#faf7fd">
        <ul class="navigation">
          <li><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="./products.html">Products</a></li>
        </ul>
      </body>
```

you can create pretty impressive page transitions.

On a side note check the code below and see if this is the effect you desire.

The issue with this would be that the previously visited link will not have a transition

Comment: To be honest, I only want to transition from page to page with only ONE background color and not have multiple background colors.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer i think its not possible to do that with pure CSS as the new page has no idea what the color on the previous page was to do the transition.

Comment: So you will be using only two colors on each tab ? For example black to yellow throughout if the page is active.

Comment: Hey take a look again at my edited comment which I put in bold replying back to you for code example from the video that I downloaded the file from.

Comment: I think an effect like this would have to suffice https://jsfiddle.net/dcannon96/m4fegczn/4/ Just click on run and you'll see what I'm talking about from the nav menu

Comment: You can't not achieve this by using CSS. **why?** simple, you are calling a **new page** and the previous *css transition* will not affect the *new page*. You can make tabs and load each page as a tab content or make an animation in each page to show the transition from *Home* to *About* as example.

Comment: I agree with @Teocci , It's what I am trying to convey too. There is no way to put a transition on a previously clicked link as CSS can not keep in memory of what page was visited previously.

Comment: @Azazel check the new code example. Although you cant animate the previously visited page link you can animate the current page link